# Water vapor in CO2 - a chemical reaction?

Tags: water, carbon-dioxide

I am doing some work on measuring water content of a stream of CO2 at ambient temperatures (25°C).

My question is this: Am I dealing with purely a mixture of gases, or is there some chemical reactions involved? If so, to what degree? I assume there is a reversible reaction to H2CO3

If this is the case, it might alter the measurements.
Analysis techniques include optical and microwave

Comment: That would be "$\ce{H2CO3}$" and it's not detectable even in water saturated with $\ce{CO2}$.

Comment: @Mithoron Not even by NMR?

Comment: NMR is too darn insensitive. You would need IR and/or mass spectrometry combined. The relavant paper is "Ludwig, R. and Kornath, A., 2000. In spite of the chemist's belief: Carbonic acid is surprisingly stable. Angewandte Chemie International Edition, 39(8), pp.1421-1423."

Comment: @Mithoron, Who said that H2CO3 is not detectable?

Comment: Gaseous carbonic acid ($\ce{H2CO3}$) is reportedly more stable than one could think, but  water vapor autocatalyzes decomposition of eventual traces of gaseous carbonic acid to carbon dioxide and more water vapor. So chances to meet carbonic acid, aside of very small equilibrium concentration in liquid water, is being trapped in deeply frozen matrix, or in interplanetary/interstellar space.

Answer (score 1):

We will not get a significant reaction in a low-density gas phase; the gas mixture is essentially $\ce{H2O + CO2}$. [Carbonic acid can be made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid), but not by reaction of carbon dioxide with water at ambient pressure.

Carbon dioxide does react slightly with liquid water to form a small amount of $\ce{H2CO3}$. But the ability to form this acid at all from carbon dioxide and water depends on the hydrogen bonding between its hydroxyl groups and surrounding water molecules. That requires the water to be densely packed in the medium, which in ordinary conditions means not in the gas phase.